# How to split list of points from picture to contiguous blocks

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, system.drawing

I have three hundreds of photos. All of them were made around one object, but it was done manually, so it needs to be adjusted. That one object should be in the same position, as i'm going to make timelapse video from these photos. And this one object should be exactly in the same place. Shifts between photos can be up to 300-500px, so it's too big. I found one red sign on that main object, and it exists on each photo, so it's my start point.

So, i have implemented small .Net application that:

1. Load each image.
2. Scans for pixels in the main area of photo
3. For each pixel it tries to compare current pixel with needed. Needed
   pixel saved as HSL numbers. All photos are a bit different in
   brightness, so it tries to search not specific color, but range of
   colors similar to needed one. So, i have acceptable deltas for each H,S and L values
4. It searches minimal X and Y coordinates for these pixels that satisfy color range
5. Then I have coordinates where that main object should be
6. Then I make new delta between minimal X and Y values and my hard coded center coordinates
7. Then I save photo as new one with these delta, so that red sign is on the same place on all photos.

Basically I have `List<Point>` for each image that satisfy color range.

But I have one problems - because of different brightness and big color range, on some photos it finds a couple of pixels that also satisfy needed color range. And if they above sign, then delta for saving is incorrect.

How can I ignore these false alarms pixels?

My current idea is group pixels by location with some delta. So group of pixels near by will be grouped as one block.

Steps for that:

1. I have list of `Point` with needed colors. Some of them can be false alarm pixel
2. then I group them by distance between them with 50px delta.
3. If some pixels are near by, then I count them as one block
4. Then i filter all blocks that has less then 40 pixels, that should be enough for my case. Currently there are just 5-20 false alarm pixels.

My current code to filter them:

```
Dictionary<Rectangle, List<Point>> blocks = new Dictionary<Rectangle, List<Point>>();
const int blockDelta = 50; // pixels delta
foreach (var point in points
{
    bool added = false;

    foreach (var rectangle in blocks.Keys)
    {
        if (point.X >= rectangle.Left && point.X <= rectangle.Right &&
            point.Y >= rectangle.Top && point.Y <= rectangle.Bottom)
        {
            blocks[rectangle].Add(point);
            added = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (added)
        continue;

    Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(point.X - blockDelta, 
            point.Y - blockDelta, blockDelta*2, blockDelta*2);

    blocks.Add(newRect, new List<Point>());
    blocks[newRect].Add(point);
}
```

But problem with that code is that if my sign has 130px width, then it will divide it to 3 blocks instead of one. And I can't increase delta, as then false alarm pixels will be also included into that block, and I want to avoid it.

Are there any better solutions for it? Or maybe you can give me some idea how to calculate such continuous blocks?

Thank you for any ideas.

**UPDATE1:**

Here is part of that image:

[image: Sample image]

I'm searching for these red signs covered by orange lines. And I use top of these signs to center image. But because of chromatic aberration on some parts of stone outlines there are a couple of red pixels, that broke logic.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Once I was working on a project involved with image processing, the problem was to find a red ball on the field. the implementation was based on BFS algorithm. the aim was to find group of adjacent 'Red-ish' pixesls with minimum number of pixels. it worked pretty well in the project. my suggestion is to use the same method and find center of each pixel group as your calibration points.

Answer (score 1):

1.the false alarm pixels is bright or dark pixels, vary a lot from the red pixels, so I suggest  using rgb instead.

2.after using threshold choosing the "wanted" pixels ,you can try dilatation to get the missed "wanted" pixels back , since there is only four big stars in each image,you can select the top four pixel group according to the number of pixels it contains
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: brightness of images and needed color are vary a lot. For example on the lightest one it's 355, 79, 66 in HSL and on darkest one is 346, 85, 24 in HSL, that's why there are false alarms. I'll try to use dilatation, thank you.